# Windows 10 Storage Space doesn't show up on new install

Tags: windows-10, storage-spaces

I have a working Windows 10 install on a SATA SSD, with a Storage Space set up with several drives. Today, I installed Windows 10 on a new NVMe drive, and the Storage Space doesn't show up. The drives that make up the Storage Space *do* show up in UEFI, Device Manager, and Intel RST.

If I plug the old SSD back in and boot to the old install, the Storage Space shows up.

I've searched online and everything suggests that Windows should automatically detect the Storage Space. Looking for any guidance.

EDIT: I have a support case open with Microsoft. Level 1 techs couldn't figure it out, so I have a Level 2 tech call set up. One weird thing I noticed is that the old install shows an extra drive (5 instead of 4) in device manager, and an extra device called "Microsoft Storage Spaces Device" under Disk Drives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This resolved itself after I received "Feature update to Windows 10, version 1803", which seems to have taken a while to apply after I installed Windows. The Storage Space was automatically detected as expected.

This suggests some kind of incompatibility between update versions of Windows 10 from a Storage Spaces perspective (I created this Storage Space well over a year ago), which is awful because nowhere on the Storage Spaces interface does it suggest that this might happen. I will follow up with Microsoft support so they can either fix this or at least improve messaging/documentation.